# How to specify region when creating a Watson service using the ibmcloud command line

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, ibm-cloud-tools

I'd like to create speech-to-text service in specify "Tokyo region" by ibmcloud command.

I knew, I can create speech-to-text service in specify "Tokyo region" by ibmcloud portal.

could you tell me please how to create service specify region.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ibmcloud resource service-instance-create myspeechtotext speech-to-text lite jp-tok
```

Here is how I figured this out:

```
$ ibmcloud regions
Listing regions...

Name       Display name
au-syd     Sydney
jp-osa     Osaka
jp-tok     Tokyo
eu-de      Frankfurt
eu-gb      London
us-south   Dallas
us-east    Washington DC

$ ibmcloud catalog search speech
Getting catalog entries...
OK
Id                                     Name                 Kind
oss.speech-to-text                     oss.speech-to-text   oss
oss.text-to-speech                     oss.text-to-speech   oss
bc35fb8c-bc5b-431b-859e-3861771d5843   speech-to-text       service
282c1d79-9176-4597-9cff-941a8d6cfd4c   text-to-speech       service

$ ibmcloud catalog entry bc35fb8c-bc5b-431b-859e-3861771d5843
Getting catalog entry...
OK
ID                                     Name             Kind      Group   Provider   Tags
bc35fb8c-bc5b-431b-859e-3861771d5843   speech-to-text   service   false   IBM        apidocs_enabled,eu_access,gc_migrate,ibm_created,ibm_dedicated_public,ibm_release,lite,rc_compatible,watson

$ ibmcloud resource service-instance-create --help
NAME:
  service-instance-create - Create a service instance

USAGE:
   ibmcloud resource service-instance-create NAME (SERVICE_NAME | SERVICE_ID) SERVICE_PLAN_NAME LOCATION [-d, --deployment DEPLOYMENT_NAME] [-p, --parameters @JSON_FILE | JSON_STRING ] [-g RESOURCE_GROUP] [--service-endpoints SERVICE_ENDPOINTS_TYPE]

OPTIONS:
   -d value, --deployment value  Name of deployment
   -p value, --parameters value  JSON file or JSON string of parameters to create service instance
   -g value                      Resource group name
   --service-endpoints value     Types of the service endpoints. Possible values are 'public', 'private', 'public-and-private'.


$ ibmcloud resource service-instance-create myspeechtotext speech-to-text lite jp-tok
```